# using java.util.logging across multiple classes

Tags: java, logging

I found this example of using java.util.logging online [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Logging/article.html). I don't understand how to modify it to use the sample across multiple classes
do I just declare this in every class?

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);
```

also in the class, they supplied there is a syntax error:

```
// suppress the logging output to the console
Logger rootLogger = Logger.*getLogger*("");
```

what is the correct way to get to the root logger?

```
package com.vogella.logger;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Formatter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

public class MyLogger {
    static private FileHandler fileTxt;
    static private SimpleFormatter formatterTxt;

    static private FileHandler fileHTML;
    static private Formatter formatterHTML;

    static public void setup() throws IOException {

        // get the global logger to configure it
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);

        // suppress the logging output to the console
        Logger rootLogger = Logger.*getLogger*("");
        Handler[] handlers = rootLogger.getHandlers();
        if (handlers[0] instanceof ConsoleHandler) {
            rootLogger.removeHandler(handlers[0]);
        }

        logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        fileTxt = new FileHandler("Logging.txt");
        fileHTML = new FileHandler("Logging.html");

        // create a TXT formatter
        formatterTxt = new SimpleFormatter();
        fileTxt.setFormatter(formatterTxt);
        logger.addHandler(fileTxt);

        // create an HTML formatter
        formatterHTML = new MyHtmlFormatter();
        fileHTML.setFormatter(formatterHTML);
        logger.addHandler(fileHTML);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**. Using [GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME) as stated in the linked Javadoc as well serves as logging using the global logger from each class. Though the usefulness is not much as it is a default java logger provided.

> `GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME` is a name for the global logger. This name is
>   provided as a convenience to developers who are making casual use of
>   the Logging package....
>
> The preferred way to get the global logger object is via the call `Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME)`.

It's also an alternate of [`Logger.getGlobal()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#global) from the older jdk versions.

---

To configure the root logger use :-

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("");
```

Comment: thank you sir, any idea about the other question  (Logger rootLogger = Logger.*getLogger*("");)